# Have you ever see this problem on Django : frozen importlib._bootstrap

Tags: django, lib

```
(env) PS C:\Users\wolf\Desktop\DashBoardv2\DashBoardv2> python manage.py migrate  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wolf\Desktop\DashBoardv2\DashBoardv2\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\wolf\Desktop\DashBoardv2\DashBoardv2\manage.py", line 18, in main
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\wolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 879, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1017, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 947, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I created a project in django. And after having created my connection with my database and a router.py because I use a router page as I have databases.

I don't use bootstrap in my project that's why I'm surprised to have this error that I don't understand and that I haven't been able to pass for several hours already!

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Don't post bilingual questions, nor ask for people to help you in any other language lease

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an encoding problem to me. Did you edit your code outside an IDE? You can use tools like Notepad ++ or similar to check the encoding. If there are weird characters in your code (hopefully first line), you should delete those.

Comment: I try to do this but i have the same error